# Add subview on the top of every ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want to place a Custom UIView over every view controller screen. I want to do this to show the download progress of video. I create a custom view using xib and use this code -:

```
 let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    window.subviews(CustomView)
```

but this code is not working how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```swift
UIApplication.topWindow.addSubview(CustomView)

extension UIApplication {
  
  static var topWindow: UIWindow {
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
      let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
      let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
      return windowScene!.windows.first!
    }
    return UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first!
  }
}
```

Comment: why not simply `UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)`? This way you don't have to iterate all windows. Btw don't force unwrap the result

Comment: Nice! @LeoDabus

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code to add the subview in the viewcontroller.

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.addSubview(CustomView)
```